# How much power dissipated in a wire?

Tags: power, wire, vlsi, parasitic-capacitance

i"m designing a long metal1 wire. The parasitic capacitors and resistors are callculated.
I want to have an ac voltage at the output end of the line ( 0 - 3.3 V ) at 1GHz.
How can i calculate the power i need to supply at the input of the line and the dissipated power?

Comment: Sorry about not being clear enough... the wire i was talking about is 3 mm wire interconnact on chip.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "long" in terms of wavelengths, and the wavelength is just 30 cm at 1 GHz.

Calculating losses in transmission lines is a complex task. You'll have both resistive losses in the conductor(s) themselves, plus dielectric losses in the surrounding materials.

One thing you'll have to add to your model is the self-inductance of the wire, which is another way of saying that you need to know its characteristic impedance. Losses will be least if the wire is terminated at both ends by its characteristic impedance, which will eliminate standing waves on the wire.

If you have standing waves, the peak current in the wire will rise, increasing the I<sup>2</sup>R losses, and the peak voltage will also rise, increasing the dielectric losses.

Comment: I've seen you give many great answers here so I don't want to sound critical, but I assumed that the "VLSI" tag meant we were dealing with a much shorter wire.

Comment: @JoeHass: Interesting thought. I assumed that we were talking about a trace on a PCB that was meant to drive the clock input of a (VLSI) chip. If the OP is actually designing complex chips at this level of physical level, he's probably out of his depth.

Comment: I meant, "at this level of physical detail"

Answer (score 0):

For a time-varying voltage applied to a resistor, the instantaneous power dissipated is just the current through the resistor times the voltage across the resistor. According to Ohm's theory, the voltage is equal to I*R so the instantaneous power dissipation is \$i^2(t)R\$. Integrate that over the period of the signal, divide by the period, and you have the average power. Now, to find the current you need to know the load capacitance at the end of the wire, and calculate \$i(t) = C dv(t)/dt\$ for your 3.3V, 1 GHz signal. If the capacitance of the wire is significant when compared to the load capacitance then the problem gets harder, and at that point I would suggest taking your netlist of parasitic R and C values into SPICE.

Comment: Ohm's theory? I always thought it was a Law :)

Comment: I always thought it was a definition (of *resistance*).

Comment: I think the answer is more complicated than a simple Ohm's law calculation. The 'long' wire (> wavelength) will act as a transmission line for a 1GHz signal. (Essentially the core wire of coax).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line   The end termination will determine how the signal is reflected back along the wire (standing wave ratio). The actual resistance of the wire per unit length will also be much higher than expected due to the skin effect (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) The calculation given in this answer refers to much lower frequencies.

Comment: @JImDearden Since the OP included the "VLSI" tag on the question I assumed that we were talking about a wire much shorter than 30 cm, something on a reasonably sized integrated circuit.

Comment: @JoeHass That's the problem if folks don't actually specify dimensions and use vague terms such as 'long wire'.I know its very easy to make assumptions to fill in the missing details (done that, got the T shirt and got roasted for it, the knife scars are healing slowly). I wasn't trying to be over picky about it like some folks on here. The phrase 'long wire' from my radio amateur days signifies a relationship with wavelength. Just trying to clarify the actual problem and make sure all the bases were covered.

Comment: @JoeHass My apologies, you were correct about where the 'long wire' was. At 3mm (1/100th wavelength) the transmission line effects should be minimal but if there is a calculation of the resistance of 'the wire' (resistivity,cross-sectional area and length) it will have to take into account the skin effect that would increase the resistance.